# Am uploading a csv file to an endpoint. Web side of the flutter code works but the mobile side throws DioException 403(forbidden)

Tags: flutter, exception, dio

Am uploading a csv file to an endpoint using the Dio Package. The Web side of the flutter code works that is the csv file is uploaded without any error. However, the flutter mobile sidethrows an exception with error status code 403: Forbidden. What could I be doing wrong. Here is what I have tried:
Am uploading a csv file to an endpoint using the Dio Package. The Web side of the flutter code works that is the csv file is uploaded without any error. However, the flutter mobile sidethrows an exception with error status code 403: Forbidden. What could I be doing wrong. Here is what I have tried:
Am uploading a csv file to an endpoint using the Dio Package. The Web side of the flutter code works that is the csv file is uploaded without any error. However, the flutter mobile sidethrows an exception with error status code 403: Forbidden. What could I be doing wrong. Here is what I have tried:

```js
Future < Uint8List > fileToUint8List(File file) async {
  final List < int > bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
  final Uint8List uint8List = Uint8List.fromList(bytes);
  return uint8List;
}

Future < void > uploadCSVFileWebAndMobile(addUser, dealerId) async {
  if (_selectedFile == null) {
    return;
  }

  if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android ||
    defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
    // Convert bytes to string (assuming it's a text file)
    debugPrint('bytes$bytes');
    String content = String.fromCharCodes(bytes as Uint8List);

    // Parse the CSV content
    List < List < dynamic >> csvData =
      const CsvToListConverter().convert(content);

    debugPrint("Original content $content");
    // Check if there's a header row and remove it (assuming the header is in the first row)
    if (csvData.isNotEmpty) {
      csvData.removeAt(0); // Remove the first row (header)
    }

    // Convert the modified CSV data back to CSV format
    String modifiedContent =
      const ListToCsvConverter().convert(csvData);

    debugPrint("Modifided content $modifiedContent");

    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'file': MultipartFile.fromString(modifiedContent, filename: filename),
      'add_user': addUser.toString(),
      'dealer_id': dealerId.toString(),
    });

    try {
      var response = await Dio().post(
        ApiEndpoints.upLoadEndPoint, // Replace with your upload URL
        data: formData,
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // File uploaded successfully
        debugPrint('File uploaded');
      } else {
        // Handle error
        debugPrint('${response.statusCode}');
        debugPrint('File upload failed');
      }
    }
    on DioException
    catch (error) {
      if (error.response != null) {
        debugPrint('Error uploading data: ${error.response!.data}');
        debugPrint(
          'Error uploading options: ${error.response!.requestOptions.path}');
      } else {
        // Handle network or other errors
        debugPrint('Error uploading file: $error');
        debugPrint('Error uploading message: ${error.message}');
        debugPrint('Error uploading requestOptions: ${error.requestOptions}');
      }
    }
  } else {
    Uint8List bytes = result!.files.single.bytes!;
    String filename = result!.files.single.name;

    // Convert bytes to string (assuming it's a text file)
    String content = String.fromCharCodes(bytes);

    // Parse the CSV content
    List < List < dynamic >> csvData =
      const CsvToListConverter().convert(content);

    debugPrint("Original content $content");
    // Check if there's a header row and remove it (assuming the header is in the first row)
    if (csvData.isNotEmpty) {
      csvData.removeAt(0); // Remove the first row (header)
    }

    // Convert the modified CSV data back to CSV format
    String modifiedContent =
      const ListToCsvConverter().convert(csvData);

    debugPrint("Modifided content $modifiedContent");

    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'file': MultipartFile.fromString(modifiedContent, filename: filename),
      'add_user': addUser.toString(),
      'dealer_id': dealerId.toString(),
    });

    try {
      var response = await Dio().post(
        ApiEndpoints.upLoadEndPoint, // Replace with your upload URL
        data: formData,
        // options: options
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // File uploaded successfully
        debugPrint('File uploaded');
      } else {
        // Handle error
        debugPrint('${response.statusCode}');
        debugPrint('File upload failed');
      }
    }
    on DioException
    catch (error) {
      // Handle network or other errors
      debugPrint('Error uploading file: $error');
      debugPrint('Error uploading message: ${error.message}');
    }
  }
}
```